# HDF5 internal data organization and NumPy usage

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables

as hdf5 documentation says, HDF5 stores data using NumPy

*"It is built on top of the HDF5 library, the Python language and the NumPy package. It features an object-oriented interface that, combined with C extensions for the performance-critical parts of the code, makes it a fast yet extremely easy-to-use tool for interactively storing and retrieving very large amounts of data"*

...

*"PyTables uses these NumPy containers as in-memory buffers to push the I/O bandwith towards the platform limits."*

So what's the mechanism? How does PyTables are using NumPy?In the end, they generate plain hdf5 accessible from other languages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDF5 is a C language library.  [HDF5 stores numbers, including floats, in a platform independent manner](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.intro.html#Intro-ODatasets) (scroll down to the table titled "Examples of Native Datatypes and Corresponding C Types," [there's more information in the Users Guide](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/UG_frame11Datatypes.html)).

PyTables simply converts from the HDF5 datatype to a NumPy datatype.  And it mixes Python code and native code to reduce I/O overhead.